# why in kafka 2.1.1 zstd is 5 time SLOWER than gzip?

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm testing kafka compression speed on topics, but I'm getting some weird results, ZSTD is 5x slower than GZIP, here some output..

### zstd

```sh
docker exec -ti compose-single_kafka_1   bash -c '/opt/kafka/bin/kafka-producer-perf-test.sh --topic test_bench --throughput 4000000 --record-size 1000 --num-records 4000000 --producer-props bootstrap.servers="127.0.0.1:9092"   compression.type=zstd batch.size=500000'
9789 records sent, 1956.2 records/sec (1.87 MB/sec), 24.9 ms avg latency, 223.0 max latency.
11061 records sent, 2211.8 records/sec (2.11 MB/sec), 24.0 ms avg latency, 91.0 max latency.
11049 records sent, 2208.9 records/sec (2.11 MB/sec), 25.0 ms avg latency, 76.0 max latency.
11183 records sent, 2232.1 records/sec (2.13 MB/sec), 23.4 ms avg latency, 89.0 max latency.
11760 records sent, 2346.4 records/sec (2.24 MB/sec), 23.2 ms avg latency, 89.0 max latency.
11218 records sent, 2239.6 records/sec (2.14 MB/sec), 23.7 ms avg latency, 93.0 max latency.
10892 records sent, 2178.0 records/sec (2.08 MB/sec), 23.8 ms avg latency, 94.0 max latency.
...
```

### gzip

```sh
docker exec -ti compose-single_kafka_1   bash -c '/opt/kafka/bin/kafka-producer-perf-test.sh --topic test_bench_gz --throughput 4000000 --record-size 1000 --num-records 4000000 --producer-props bootstrap.servers="127.0.0.1:9092" compression.type=gzip batch.size=500000'
50240 records sent, 10048.0 records/sec (9.58 MB/sec), 6.6 ms avg latency, 208.0 max latency.
60849 records sent, 12109.3 records/sec (11.55 MB/sec), 5.4 ms avg latency, 55.0 max latency.
59617 records sent, 11923.4 records/sec (11.37 MB/sec), 5.6 ms avg latency, 47.0 max latency.
61800 records sent, 12360.0 records/sec (11.79 MB/sec), 5.4 ms avg latency, 50.0 max latency.
64763 records sent, 12952.6 records/sec (12.35 MB/sec), 5.1 ms avg latency, 48.0 max latency.
58560 records sent, 11712.0 records/sec (11.17 MB/sec), 5.8 ms avg latency, 48.0 max latency.
57930 records sent, 11586.0 records/sec (11.05 MB/sec), 5.8 ms avg latency, 47.0 max latency.
57360 records sent, 11472.0 records/sec (10.94 MB/sec), 5.8 ms avg latency, 48.0 max latency.
64080 records sent, 12810.9 records/sec (12.22 MB/sec), 5.2 ms avg latency, 39.0 max latency.
57120 records sent, 11401.2 records/sec (10.87 MB/sec), 5.8 ms avg latency, 83.0 max latency.
```

Answer (score 2):

further testing evidenced that zstd seems to have higher fixed costs which make it slower than gzip for small batches, in the above test the batch was high (maybe too high? because something else may be entered in the equation ) here are some more results.. zstd is faster on some usecase, but on other is slower ( A LOT SLOWER!
when compression on producer + recompression on broker is enabled (instead of producer only  I've seen also 50X slower of zstd vs gzip in some tests.. )

this thing is not documented, and even on google is never mentioned.. but it's IMPORTANT. test your usecase carefully! ( with your ~production data & ~batching size )

```sh
 Fri Mar 08 09:51:28   @@@@on  wk1                                                                                                                                   
 ~  hist:2434  jobs:0 $docker exec -ti compose-single_kafka_client_1   bash -c '/opt/kafka/bin/kafka-producer-perf-test.sh --topic test_bench_rnd_gz --throughput 4000000 --record-size 1000 --num-records 2000000 --producer-props bootstrap.servers="kafka:9092"   compression.type=gzip batch.size=10000'
[2019-03-08 09:51:53,704] WARN [Producer clientId=producer-1] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 1 : {test_bench_rnd_gz=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE} (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
408109 records sent, 81621.8 records/sec (77.84 MB/sec), 27.4 ms avg latency, 329.0 max latency.
491153 records sent, 98230.6 records/sec (93.68 MB/sec), 2.5 ms avg latency, 62.0 max latency.
513725 records sent, 102745.0 records/sec (97.99 MB/sec), 3.0 ms avg latency, 44.0 max latency.
514983 records sent, 102996.6 records/sec (98.23 MB/sec), 2.0 ms avg latency, 26.0 max latency.
2000000 records sent, 96679.073814 records/sec (92.20 MB/sec), 7.53 ms avg latency, 329.00 ms max latency, 2 ms 50th, 26 ms 95th, 160 ms 99th, 283 ms 99.9th.

 Fri Mar 08 09:52:14   @@@@on  wk1 
 ~  hist:2435  jobs:0 $docker exec -ti compose-single_kafka_client_1   bash -c '/opt/kafka/bin/kafka-producer-perf-test.sh --topic test_bench_rnd_zstd --throughput 4000000 --record-size 1000 --num-records 2000000 --producer-props bootstrap.servers="kafka:9092"   compression.type=zstd batch.size=10000'
569352 records sent, 113870.4 records/sec (108.60 MB/sec), 336.4 ms avg latency, 821.0 max latency.
776529 records sent, 155305.8 records/sec (148.11 MB/sec), 481.2 ms avg latency, 1120.0 max latency.
2000000 records sent, 138504.155125 records/sec (132.09 MB/sec), 410.25 ms avg latency, 1120.00 ms max latency, 406 ms 50th, 733 ms 95th, 999 ms 99th, 1102 ms 99.9th.

 Fri Mar 08 09:52:47   @@@@on  wk1 
 ~  hist:2436  jobs:0 $docker exec -ti compose-single_kafka_client_1   bash -c '/opt/kafka/bin/kafka-producer-perf-test.sh --topic test_bench_rnd_zstd --throughput 4000000 --record-size 1000 --num-records 2000000 --producer-props bootstrap.servers="kafka:9092"   compression.type=zstd batch.size=1000000'
1029044 records sent, 205808.8 records/sec (196.27 MB/sec), 166.6 ms avg latency, 354.0 max latency.
2000000 records sent, 218316.777644 records/sec (208.20 MB/sec), 148.01 ms avg latency, 354.00 ms max latency, 155 ms 50th, 264 ms 95th, 315 ms 99th, 348 ms 99.9th.

 Fri Mar 08 09:53:21   @@@@on  wk1 
 ~  hist:2437  jobs:0 $docker exec -ti compose-single_kafka_client_1   bash -c '/opt/kafka/bin/kafka-producer-perf-test.sh --topic test_bench_rnd_gz --throughput 4000000 --record-size 1000 --num-records 2000000 --producer-props bootstrap.servers="kafka:9092"   compression.type=gzip batch.size=1000000'
422704 records sent, 84540.8 records/sec (80.62 MB/sec), 1.9 ms avg latency, 195.0 max latency.
472069 records sent, 94413.8 records/sec (90.04 MB/sec), 2.7 ms avg latency, 71.0 max latency.
503248 records sent, 100649.6 records/sec (95.99 MB/sec), 2.0 ms avg latency, 41.0 max latency.
502847 records sent, 100569.4 records/sec (95.91 MB/sec), 1.6 ms avg latency, 27.0 max latency.
2000000 records sent, 94944.220271 records/sec (90.55 MB/sec), 1.99 ms avg latency, 195.00 ms max latency, 1 ms 50th, 3 ms 95th, 20 ms 99th, 58 ms 99.9th.

 Fri Mar 08 09:53:45   @@@@on  wk1 
 ~  hist:2438  jobs:0 $docker exec -ti compose-single_kafka_client_1   bash -c '/opt/kafka/bin/kafka-producer-perf-test.sh --topic test_bench_rnd_zstd --throughput 4000000 --record-size 1000 --num-records 2000000 --producer-props bootstrap.servers="kafka:9092"   compression.type=zstd batch.size=1'
3473 records sent, 686.9 records/sec (0.66 MB/sec), 1283.5 ms avg latency, 3578.0 max latency.
2662 records sent, 530.2 records/sec (0.51 MB/sec), 5465.4 ms avg latency, 7542.0 max latency.
4760 records sent, 944.3 records/sec (0.90 MB/sec), 10111.7 ms avg latency, 10959.0 max latency.
9362 records sent, 1872.4 records/sec (1.79 MB/sec), 11933.1 ms avg latency, 13012.0 max latency.
9560 records sent, 1912.0 records/sec (1.82 MB/sec), 13789.4 ms avg latency, 14587.0 max latency.
10085 records sent, 2017.0 records/sec (1.92 MB/sec), 15471.3 ms avg latency, 16141.0 max latency.
10007 records sent, 2001.4 records/sec (1.91 MB/sec), 15883.0 ms avg latency, 16088.0 max latency.
9467 records sent, 1893.4 records/sec (1.81 MB/sec), 15662.6 ms avg latency, 15754.0 max latency.
^C
 Fri Mar 08 09:54:56   @@@@on  wk1 
 ~  hist:2439  jobs:0 $docker exec -ti compose-single_kafka_client_1   bash -c '/opt/kafka/bin/kafka-producer-perf-test.sh --topic test_bench_rnd_gz --throughput 4000000 --record-size 1000 --num-records 2000000 --producer-props bootstrap.servers="kafka:9092"   compression.type=gzip batch.size=1'
17263 records sent, 3452.6 records/sec (3.29 MB/sec), 2364.6 ms avg latency, 3925.0 max latency.
25109 records sent, 5021.8 records/sec (4.79 MB/sec), 5645.0 ms avg latency, 6540.0 max latency.
26191 records sent, 5238.2 records/sec (5.00 MB/sec), 6012.7 ms avg latency, 6207.0 max latency.
25398 records sent, 5079.6 records/sec (4.84 MB/sec), 6012.9 ms avg latency, 6107.0 max latency.
```

have a nice day ,
Francesco

Comment: `zstd` can vary the amount of resources used to match exactly needed amount for a given source and compression parameters.
Additionally, `zstd` can re-use existing resources when compressing a batch of small files. In which case, it's very fast for small files.

However, both features can be circumvented by the caller. For example, if the caller destroys the context after each compression, it makes it impossible to reuse its resources for next compression. So a new context must be created, and initialized, which can be costly.
So it's also a matter of how Kafka implemented `zstd` support.

Comment: Strangely in my testing I've similar results and have also found that compression type of none had better throughput than zstd even.